# Как будет лучше с точки зрения оптимизации? Как включать стили только на определенной странице. wordpress

Tags: wordpress

У меня такой вопрос. К сожалению нет наставника и не знаю где почерпнуть данные знания.

Допустим я делаю сайт в несколько страниц.
На главной одни стили, на странице контактов другие стили, на третьей странице третьи стили (естественно есть общие стили, я их подключаю отдельно).

Во-первых, есть ли смысл подключать отдельные стилевые файлы на каждую страницу? По идее так можно оптимизировать, но с другой стороны если человек переходит с главной страницы, а затем на другую страницу, то стили уже в хеше и не надо их подгружать для новой страницы.
Как имеет смысл делать? Подскажите может какие-нибудь статьи, или жизненный опыт.

Во-вторых: если все же подгружать для каждой страницы свои стили, то как на Wordpress реализовать данную функцию? 
Спасибо!

Comment: Это сделать можно, но смысл примерно нулевой. Файлы стилей в 10 тыс строк загружаются мгновенно, кеширование на сервере и в браузерах позволяет просто забыть об этой экономии на спичках.

Comment: Вот вам пример: небольшой сайт, почти без кеширования. Загружается 1.3 сек по PageSpeed. Общее кол-во строк css в ядре+теме+плагинах - 107 тысяч. Теперь посчитайте кол-во сэкономленных вами строк, поделите на 107 тысяч и увидите, сколько миллисекунд вы сэкономили. И сравните с кол-вом потраченных на оптимизацию часов.

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо! Как раз тот дельный совет, который мне и нужен был! Можете сделать это ответом, я отмечу. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это сделать можно, но смысл примерно нулевой. Файлы стилей в 10 тыс строк загружаются мгновенно, кеширование на сервере и в браузерах позволяет просто забыть об этой экономии на спичках.

Вот вам пример: небольшой сайт, почти без кеширования. Загружается 1.3 сек по Pingdom. Общее кол-во строк css в ядре+теме+плагинах - 107 тысяч. Теперь посчитайте кол-во сэкономленных вами строк, поделите на 107 тысяч и увидите, сколько миллисекунд вы сэкономили. Сравните с количеством потраченных на оптимизацию часов.